# Quitting DOS Program and booting Windows OS

Tags: boot, windows-98, windows-95

I have a really old System (Fujitsu ICL ErgoPro e450) It is set up so that it boots into DOS mode and then runs a DOS Program.

My question is how would I quit this program, close DOS mode and Reboot into the Windows OS (possibly 95 or 98)? I would prefer not to turn the computer off during this process with the computer being so old I don't want it to fail due to stress, it was a nightmare trying to get it to boot thus far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were no Windows 98 se system files present on the C drive but in fact the setup files for windows 98 its now running a new installation of windows 98 I happened to have a license for it too so its all good thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on how to quit the dos application - this varies by program, however try ctrl+c, which was a fairly common cancellation method.

From here, to boot to windows, the possible commands you need are:

- Exit
- win (C:\windows\win.com)
- C:\autoexec.bat

Try these and one of them should get you into windows for 95 or 98

However, autoexec.bat is part of your boot process and if this ms-dos program kicks off at boot, it is most likely in autoexec, so leave this option)

Comment: Running autoexec.bat will just start the dos program again as this is the Auto Executing part of the boot process. The usual way to start Windows in the <= Win98 period is to run C:\Windows\win.com

Comment: answer updated - its been a while!

Comment: I believe `exit` is all that is needed if it is indeed a “DOS session” initiated from Windows. Unfortunately, I don’t have a Win 9x VM handy at the moment, so I can’t verify.